# How to add a TXT record to zone to prove ownership

Tags: googledns

How do you add a TXT record to a google dns zone to prove ownership of domain?

I am trying to setup [knative](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/using-cert-manager-on-gcp/) to use letsencrypt and I can see that I need to do some TXT setup on a record set - but what values?

Note: I have a Godaddy domain where I am using google name servers.

Answer (score 3):

1.Go into the DNS management page on google domains.

2.Add the following TXT records below to the DNS server for specific domain.Add TXT record with the name/host

key with the value XXXX

You may have to wait a minute to a couple minutes for the DNS TXT record to propagate if the TTL record value does not show up or is not the same as the above values.

As i can see you are trying to use let's encrypt for ssl you can try sslforfree.com